# How to ensure consistency across 2 collections in mongodb without transaction

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have recently been working on my chat app design. So far, I have 2 designs in mind.

The first one is to have chat messages and members embedded. And members are gonna have an unread message count and last read time. The problem with this approach is massive collection problem. And messages never queried along with chat, so probably waste of memory as well.

[first design](https://monosnap.com/file/mE1Luzq1atRQFjtTLiGb6yegLvAdxt)

The second design is to have a separate message collection with reference to the chat. Members still will be embedded.

But with the second approach, there is a problem with the query. When I insert a new message, I need to update the chat with `lastMessage` and update the user `unreadCount`. But I want to do that without transaction since it is too expensive and not really scalable for high load (or at least will be expensive). I thought about doing it without transaction, but can be a race condition when two users insert message at the same time, but the message that was sent first will update chat with last message. I can potentially solve it by updating chat only if `lastMessageTimestamp < new message timestamp`. But what if my request to mongo fails? There will be an inconsistency and how can I solve it (maybe use queue)?

Answer (score 2):

Since `lastMessage` and `unreadCount` are basically derived values, I suggest you to not store them separately. You will always have an issue with race conditions and keeping data in sync when you store it in two different places.

Solution: You should focus on retrieving the derived data while querying for the actual chat object. In your case it's probably suitable to use an aggregation pipeline with a `$lookup` stage in it. In order to prevent bottlenecks you should think about creating an index for this kind of relation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a question though. In my schema lastMessage and unreadCount are in the same collection. Therefore, there isn't going to be a race condition. But I am afraid, what if I inserted message successfully, but update on chat failed. That would make db inconsistent. Otherwise, your solution would probably work, but I think lookups are quite expensive (but since write query is a lot often, it may make sense to use lookup)

Comment: I am pretty sure that in your case  the additional write operations (for each new message) are more expensive than performing a lookup on an indexed property during reading of chat objects.